# Execute multiple zmq send in same event loop with php ratchet

Tags: php, zeromq, ratchet

I have a list of 500 results that I want to send from my zmq worker class to my server class. Now I am trying to send the first 50 results and then do some processing for the next 450 results and then send them on the same zmq socket. But what i see is on the server side I am getting both the response together. I was expecting that the first 50 results will reach server and the server can send it to client and when it gets the other 450 results it can then send it back to client. Below is the code that I use

Server Code File

```
$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pusher = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$pusher->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8889");
$applicationObj = new ServerApplication($pusher);

$sink = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$sink->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8888");

$sink->on("message", function ($message) use ($applicationObj) {
    TODO: SEND MESSAGE TO CLIENT
});

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen($options["serverport"], "0.0.0.0"); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer($applicationObj)
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

Worker Code File

```
$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);

$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8889');

$push = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$push->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8888');


$pull->on('message', function($message) use ($loop, $push) {
        $response = []; (this is an array of initial 50 results)
        $push->send($response);
        $next_res = get_next_450_results();
        $new_resp = [];  (this is array of next 450 results)
        $push->send($new_resp)
});
$loop->run();
```

Can someone please help me with the issue here, basically I am not able to send the response from worker to server in paginated way.
I am using php ratchet and zmq.